# What is the significance of a return statement in a procedure of void type

Tags: c#, com-interop, return, void

Is there any significance for a return statement in a void procedure.

I had a scenario where I am using some COM Interop and the runtime behaviour was strange. The code executes fine when I debug using Visual Studio, But it misbehaves when executed from an exe. No exceptions are thrown in any case.
    My code was something like this.

```
private void function1()
{
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(messageInfo.DisplayText, GlobalData.MessageCaption, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    minSize = (int)numericUpdown.Value;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    minSize = sampleSize;
                    return; //This is the return statement in question
                }
}
```

The issue was resolved when I added a return statement inside the else block[There are no lines after the return statement.]. I confirmed by repeatedly testing the issue with and without the return statement, and am now confused about what exactly is happening.

Does this have any change in the way the application behaves.

Comment: Is anything else happening after the `else`?

Comment: @BoltClock No;the return is the last statement.

Answer (score 2):

The method will return and any remaining code will not execute.  This depends on a few thing though, like whether the return is in a using or try-catch block - as certain things run even if you explicitly return.

Void return types just can't return anything.

As for your strange issue, assuming the code is entirely what you posted, then returning will do nothing special.  I can only guess that you haven't posted all the code, which means the return might be doing something (as in, stopping the duff code from running).

Comment: In my case, the else block is the last line of code that is executed[with or without return]. There are no try catches or using blocks.

Comment: In that case, the return early will do nothing as the code is logically taking the same path without the return.  I would guess that something else is at play, perhaps a multi-threading issue, or the flag isn't the value you expect it to be?

Comment: @Vimal Raj: If the misbehavior is consistent then there is some other behavior present that's causing your problem.  I would add a LOT of logging inside the method to figure out what is actually going on.  I suspect your inputs aren't exactly what you think they are.

Comment: I have updated with my real code. There is no COM interaction inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed different behaviour when debugging and when non-debbuging, also with COM, in System.DirectoryServices.

The different behaviour seems to have something to do with COM.

IMHO, it is either a compiler or a runtime bug.